# Get all app and web config files in solution

Tags: c#, .net

I want to write a test to check some settings in my app config files are present.

How would i go about getting all of the app/web config files in the solution?

Comment: do u mean "how to access files of a specific directory?"

Comment: I want to write a test that ensures none of the app config files in my solution contain a particular setting. This should fail if i add another project to the solution and it does not contain that config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using directory searching you can get the files

```
  string[] configFiles = Directory.GetFiles( @"YourSolutonDirectoryLocation", "*.config", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                               .Where(x => x.EndsWith("App.config") || x.EndsWith("Web.config")).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand your post,
Please use following to get `all files` in a `directory`

```
public string[] GetAllFilesInDirectory(string path, string startsWith, string fileExt)
    {
        string[] filenames = Directory.GetFiles(path, startsWith + "*" + fileExt);
        return filenames;

    }
```

Usage:

```
 string[] arr= GetAllFilesInDirectory(somepath,startswith,".config");
```

Hope this helps!